# Using get_class in try - catch block

Tags: php, class, exception

**Questions**

- Is it possible to instantiate an class with the `get_class` method in PHP?
- Is it possible to use `get_class` into an `catch()` block to catch an exception from that type of error?

**My own try**

Whenever using the `get_class`, it returns the class name as a string. When I tried to instantiate it like this:

```
$classWhereExceptionObjectIsStored = new classWhereExceptionObjectIsStored();

try {
   //Some code

} catch(get_class($classWhereExceptionObjectIsStored->getExceptionObject $e)) {
   //Do stuff with the exception
}
```

It didnt work.

The class:

```
class classWhereExceptionObjectIsStored
{

    public function getExceptionObject($message) {
        return new LogicException($message); //For example
    }
}
```

**Second try**

```
$class = get_class($classWhereExceptionObjectIsStored->getExceptionInstance('hi!'));

try {
   //Some code

} catch($class $e)) {
   //Do stuff with the exception
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_class](http://php.net/get_class) returns just the name of the class, that's the use of that function. You can instantiate a class dynamically by doing:

```
new $class();
```

Which in your case would probably have to result in something like:

```
new get_class($classWhereExceptionObjectIsStored->getExceptionInstance('hi!'));
```

This doesn't work in a catch block. That's because you don't instantiate anything in a catch block - the only thing you specify there is the exception class you're expecting to get.

An alternative would be to catch all exceptions:

```
catch(Exception $e){}
```

And then within that catch use the PHP function [is_a](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) to check if the thrown exception is of the type you're expecting, like so:

```
if(is_a($e, get_class($classWhereExceptionObjectIsStored->getExceptionInstance('hi!'))){}
```

However, I truly question your motives. I can't think of any use case where this would add functionality, readability, scalability or usability.

Comment: I was just looking around some functions and came up with this idea :) But how would i use this into an `catch()` block then? Because you dont call the `new` operator there.

Comment: No. (comment too short to post)

Comment: But would it be that bad if i just have the `catch(Exception $e)` ? I guess its the same?

Comment: It really depends on your purposes whether it's bad to catch all exceptions using that clause. I have a hard time understanding your exact situation; it's usually known which exception (types) will be thrown. You can just catch them in the right hierarchical order, right? If the exception you're about to receive is always a surprise, something's wrong in your design.

Comment: No, I'm maintaining my exceptions correctly and i know which one to receive. Which are all a 'child' of the `Exception` object

Comment: Then catching them in the right order statically rather than dynamically would seem the way to go.

Comment: I mean without using 'get_class' kind of functions. If you know which exceptions to expect, catch those and drop the trickery.